# Transform a list to a list of average values (by step)

Tags: python-2.7

I have a two dimensional list of values:

```
[
[[12.2],[5325]],
[[13.4],[235326]],
[[15.9],[235326]],
[[17.7],[53521]],
[[21.3],[42342]],
[[22.6],[6546]],
[[25.9],[34634]],
[[27.2],[523523]],
[[33.4],[235325]],
[[36.2],[235352]]
]
```

I would like to get a list of averages defined by a given step so that for a `step=10` it would like like this:

```
[
[[10],[average of all 10-19]],
[[20],[average of all 20-29]],
[[30],[average of all 30-39]]
]
```

How can I achieve that? Please note that the number of 10s, 20s, 30s and so on is not always the same.

Comment: use slicing notation a[10:20] and write a function that calculates the average of a list. also, you may want to use a dictionary, not a 2d list like that

Comment: Slicing notations returns a given number of elements, not those elements which satisfy the requirement which in this case is packing them into 10's.

Comment: that's correct. you can use slicing to give you 10 elements at a time: 
`for i in range(N): a[i * 10:i*10+10]`

Comment: ok, I didn't clearly indicate it in the example but the number of 10s, 20s, 30s etc. can be different so this would not work

Comment: @PramusPL it'd show willing if your output example included the *actual* expected output as you want it computed.

Comment: @PramusPL then change the 10 to a different value... or make it a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame((q[0][0], q[1][0]) for q in thelist)
df['group'] = (df[0] / 10).astype(int)
```

Now df is:

```
      0       1  group
0  12.2    5325      1
1  13.4  235326      1
2  15.9  235326      1
3  17.7   53521      1
4  21.3   42342      2
5  22.6    6546      2
6  25.9   34634      2
7  27.2  523523      2
8  33.4  235325      3
9  36.2  235352      3
```

Then:

```
df.groupby('group').mean()
```

Gives you the answers you seek:

```
           0       1
group               
1      14.80  132374
2      24.25  151761
3      34.80  235338
```